# Invoking base class 2 argument constructor into subclass one argument constructor

Tags: c++, class-constructors, inherited-constructors

as title says I am having some problems with invoking base class constructor in subclass constructor

Base:

```
account.h
    Account(double, Customer*)
account.cpp
    Account::Account(double b, Customer *cu)
    {
    balance = b;
    cust = *cu;
    }
```

Subclass:

```
savings.h
    Savings(double);
savings.cpp
    Savings::Savings(double intRate) : Account(b, cu)
    {
    interestRate = intRate;
    }
```

Error that I am getting is b and cu are undefined.
Thanks for help

Comment: How about defining them ?

Comment: Have you considered having Savings be its own class, and then have Account optionally contain an instance of Savings (e.g., a pointer to a Savings object as a member variable of Account). That way you could add a savings object to an existing account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of how you create a `SavingsAccount`.

Can you create one using

```
SavingsAccount ac1(0.01);
```

If you did that, what would be the balance on that object? Who will be the `Customer` for that object.

You need to provide the balance as well as the `Customer` when you create a `SavingsAccount`. Something like:

```
Customer* cu = new Customer; // Or get the customer based on some other data
SavingsAccount ac1(100.0, cu, 0.01);
```

makes sense. You are providing all the data needed for a `SavingsAccount`. To create such an object, you'll need to define the constructor of `SavingsAccount` appropriately.

```
Savings::Savings(double b, Customer *cu, double intRate);
```

That can be implemented properly with:

```
Savings::Savings(double b,
                 Customer *cu,
                 double intRate) : Account(b, cu), interestRate(intRate) {}
```

Comment: Thanks much clearer now, can you just explain me why do I need the last part interestRate(intRate)?

Comment: @Zile That simply initialises `interestRate` with `intRate`

Comment: So if I write it like that I don't need line interestRate = intRate;?

Comment: @Zile That's correct

Comment: Thank you. Now its much clearer

Answer (score 0):

In your subclass `Savings` you need to define `b` and `cu` somewhere to pass to constructor of base `Account`, e.g:

```
Savings::Savings(double b, Customer* cu, double intRate) : Account(b, cu) {
    interestRate = intRate;
}
```

Such that the constructor of `Savings` takes the `double` and `Customer*` args required for passing to constructor of base class.

Comment: I have included account.h in savings.h and in account.h i have: protected:
 double balance;
 Customer cust;

Answer (score 0):

I think the previous answer is wrong because in Account you don't have to put also intRate.
So:

```
Savings::Savings(double b, Customer* cu, double intRate) : Account(b, cu)
{ interestRate = intRate; }
```

Comment: This is a question in my assignment: a three-argument constructor which invokes the Account base class two-argument constructor and then sets interestRate to the user-supplied interest rate (which the user supplies via the test driver).

Comment: Where is the three-argument constructor in your example?

Comment: I thought that 2 argument constructor is Account (b,cu) and one argument constructor is Savings(double intRate)

Comment: If you want to call the constructor of your base class (through your derived one) you have to pass the arguments through the derived class.